# Ionic Facebook plugin unstable

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ionic-framework

In my Ionic project, I'm having a randomly occuring problem when trying to get a user's facebook friends.
This is the code in my controller:

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
  console.log('SPLASHCTRL: FB: ionic is ready');
  console.log('SPLASHCTRL:FB: starting getLoginStatus()');


  $cordovaFacebook.getLoginStatus()
.then(function(success) {
      //checking if succes
      if(success.status === "connected"){
            console.log("SplashCtrl:FB: User is FB Authenticated; staying at splash");

            $cordovaFacebook.api("me/friends", ["user_friends"])
                .then(
                    function(success) {
                      console.log("SPLASHCTRL: FB: GOT FBAPP FRIENDS SUCCESFULLY: " + JSON.stringify(success));

                       $scope.fbAppFriends = success.data;
                       console.log('SPLASHCTRL: FB: SETTING LOADING TO FALSE');

                       $scope.loadingFbFriends = false;
                    // success
                   }, 
                   function (error) {
                    console.log('SPLASHCTRL: FB: ERROR GETTING FRIENDS' + JSON.stringify(error));

                  }
                );

          } else{
            console.log('SPLASHCTRL: FB: User response is not connected');

            $state.go('intro');
          }

     }, 

    function (error) {
          console.log('SPLASHCTRL: FB: Error getting login status: ' + JSON.stringify(error));

    });


});
```

when runnning this, I'm getting the log saying

```
"SplashCtrl:FB: User is FB Authenticated; staying at splash"
```

Indicating everything's fine, but after that **half of the time, nothing happens**, making it look like `$cordovaFacebook.api` isn't called.
As it turns out, everytime the function isn't called, I have an error saying:

```
    FB.getLoginStatus() called before FB.init()
```

So the strange thing here is that this error comes up from time to time, without the code being different.

Anyone else experiencing a similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using [ngCordova's Facebook plugin](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/facebook/)

ngCordova is a library for Ionic that acts as an interface between ionic and the standard cordova plugins.

From the documentation:

```
module.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaFacebook) {

    $cordovaFacebook.login(["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"])
        .then(function(success) {
           // success
        }, function (error) {
           // error
        }
    );

    $cordovaFacebook.getLoginStatus()
        .then(function(success) {
           // success
        }, function (error) {
           // error
        }
    );
});
```